# Concatenar aspas simples em variável de data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, concatenação-de-string

Tenho uma aplicação em VueJS e preciso concatenar aspas simples em uma varável que possui uma data como essa `2017-11-09T02:00:00.000Z` .

Tentei da seguinte maneira e não tive sucesso:

`var novaData = "'" + data + "'"`

Tentei utilizar a mesma metodologia no servidor, porem ele me retorno o seguinte resultado:

`'\'2017-11-02T02:00:00.000Z\''`

E por nada nesse mundo não consegui fazer o `replace()` das `\`

O que eu preciso é que depois de concatenar a string que retorne seja parecida com isso:

`'2017-11-02T02:00:00.000Z'`

pois preciso da data nesse formato para fazer consultas no MongoDB.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço...

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o formato original? tens uma string ou um objeto `Date`? Estás a enviar isso do Vue para o servidor?

Comment: Tenho um objeto `Date`, peço desculpas por me expressar mal, e sim, estou enviando do lado do cliente para o servidor

Comment: Sua pergunta está correta `Concatenar aspas SIMPLES...` ou seria `Concatenar aspas ...? Só para dar mais sentido as respostas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes enviar com o `JSON.stringify`, que cria uma string com aspas dentro da string:

```js
var date = new Date();
var string = JSON.stringify(date);
console.log(typeof string, string); // string "2017-11-09T14:12:21.523Z"
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu preciso, funcionou perfeitamente...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode retonar a string da data com [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```js
let dt = new Date();
console.log(typeof dt.toISOString(), dt.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pergunta:

Concatenar aspas simples em variável de data? `'2017-11-02T02:00:00.000Z'`

```js
var date = new Date();

var novaData = "'"+date.toISOString()+"'";

console.log(novaData);
```